# Access to Exchange CustomAttribute1 in Office365

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Let's assume we've created a new mailbox in Exchange Online (Office365) service and we've set the "`CustomAttribute1`" of this mailbox using the following command:

```
Get-Mailbox | Set-Mailbox -CustomAttribute1 'Some value'.
```

Is there any API in which those "`CustomAttribute1`, ..., `CustomAttribute15`" are exposed? I've tried many options with EWS, Microsoft Graph, AAD Graph API without success.

The only suggestions I've found related to those attributes concern the case of synchronizing them between on-permise AD and AAD (like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-feature-directory-extensions), but the account I've created is pure online.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not able to find the other way to retrieve the custom attribute set by the set-Mailbox.

As a workaround, you may create an extension to store the custom value and then you can retrieve them using the Microsoft Graph REST. More detail about the adding the custom data using Microsoft Graph, you can refer the link below:

[Add custom data to resources using extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview)

And if you want the Microsoft Graph also support to retrieve the custom attribute set by the set-Mailbox, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).